# Why -Xmt command line option not working in IBM JDK 7 release 1?

Tags: multi-tenant

I have installed IBM JDK 7 with release 1 and i am try to run Hello world program with -Xmt option on Ubuntu 14(OS installed in Virtual Box), but runtime i got Command-line option not recognized: -Xmt.
[In IBM documentation they said to create tenant use -Xmt with java command.]

Answer (score 0):

These features are no longer available in their latest release thats why. 
Check the links: [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21639279) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=aa61d6e5-75c1-4a61-b88c-6ec8d80c49c7)
They say that the had some issues but the thing is they also removed it from the developers preview page so there is no way to actually test it.